# A simple problem of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Discuss the nature of the series

$$\frac{1}{1+3^{-1}}+\frac{2}{1+3^{-2}}+\frac{3}{1+3^{-3}}+.....$$

is it converges or diverges? and why? explain!

I already have the answer in my book it says ( the series is divergent)

I tried writing the series and I came up with this:
$$\frac{n}{1+3^{-n}}$$

now if I take the limit of this I get $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{n}{1+3^{-n}}$$

$$=\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\infty}{1+3^{-\infty}}$$

Now I'm confused by the minus power of $\infty $, what should I do?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Have you written out a few terms to see what you think?

Comment: I couldn't come up with any thoughts that's why I'm asking

Comment: Write out some terms.

Comment: Apply the convergence rules? See: http://math2.org/math/expansion/tests.htm

Comment: I edited the question, have a look at it.

Comment: $3^{-n}={1\over3^n}$  What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over3^n}$?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,3^n}{3^n+1}$$

Do you think $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{n\,3^n}{3^n+1}=0\;$?

Comment: I edited the question, have a look at it.

Comment: @jonwick Is the very same series...$$\frac n{1+3^{-n}}=\frac n{\frac{3^n+1}{3^n}}=\frac{n\,3^n}{3^n+1}\ldots$$

Comment: But why it equals to zero?

Comment: @jonwick is it equal to zero? That's what the question is asking you. Alternatively in your form, what do you think $\lim_{n\to\infty}3^{-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{3^n}$ equals?

Comment: I think the limit of $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{n}{1+3^{-n}}$
$=\frac{\infty}{1+3^{-\infty}}$$=\frac{\infty}{1+\frac{1}{3^\infty}}$$=\frac{\infty}{1+0}=\infty$

Comment: @jonwick Exactly...but what matters to you is that the limit is *not* zero...

Comment: I get it now, Thanks very much.